# how to install IPA file with itms-services?

Tags: html, plist, ipa

I'm trying to set up a simple webpage that contains a link which then install an .ipa file to an IOS device. I have found several tutorials to do this and followed the needed steps. I have a webpage that has the 2 file (.ipa & .plist) that are able to be downloaded individually on their endpoints, but when i use the hyperlink as stated nothing happens.

```
hyperlink:<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=my-url-here/files/manifest.plist"">Download app</a>
.plist:
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>software-package</string>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>my-url-here</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>metadata</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                    <string>my name here</string>
                    <key>bundle-version</key>
                    <string>1.0.</string>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software</string>
                    <key>title</key>
                    <string>my-name</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Normally this link should then download the .plist file which then triggers the download & installation of the .ipa file. This does not happen sadly and i have no clue where to look to solve my problem since this is my first time working with apple products.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!